# Имитация мобильного браузера

Tags: android, python, парсер, appium, crawling

Столкнулся с творческой задачей. Нужно автоматизировать работу мобильного браузера для имитации действий пользователя в соответствии с программой которую я напишу в  будущем (кликни туда, свайпни то).

Браузер должен быть мобильным, в эмулированном андроиде

Нашел платформы  http://appium.io/ и http://selendroid.io/

К сожалению не смог приспособить под свои нужды, да и с IOS браузером беда (сафари работает только на платформе MAC), а у меня Linux сервер.

Может есть что-то попроще? Может взять банальный какой-нибудь Scrappy или обычный селениум и использовать? Но он не умееет свайпать, тапать, это просто инструмент извлечения данных. Пожалуйста намекните чем можно воспользоваться? 
Вариант просто поставить скрипту юзерагенты также не решает проблему. Например Google он насквозь видит какой браузер у клиента и ГЛАВНОЕ какое устройство. Если решить проблему с свайпами и имитацией действий, то как тогда притворяться андроидом или к примеру IOS..

За любые мысли буду крайне признателен.

Comment: Ну смотри, можно на самом деле взять Selenium, он умеет кликать и тд. главное знать код элемента, с которым будешь взаимодействовать